# Existe uma maneira de usar um elemento non Form-associated como associado de forma natural?

Tags: html, html5

No **HTML**, existem os elementos **'Form-associated'**, que são elementos que são associados ao **form** aos quais estão dentro, como o **input** por exemplo.

Bom, mas mesmo que não seja usual, se em determinada situação eu queira que um elemento **NÃO** **'Form-associated'** nativo fosse associado ao form em questão, algo como:

```
<form>
   <div value="VALOR"></div>
</form>
```

> É possível associar estes elementos apenas com HTML ? (submeter o
>   valor da div)

**OBS:** Não quero captar o valor com `JS` ou outra forma, a dúvida é se existe como tornar estes elementos associados de uma forma natural com **HTML**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta é **não**. Apenas elementos de formulário (input, textarea, select, button...) são recebidos no *backend* via `form`.

Se for estritamente necessário enviar um atributo `value` de uma `div` em um `submit` (o que não é correto, uma vez que o atributo `value` não se aplica à `div`s mas à elementos de formulário), você teria que fazer um controle via JS criando um `input hidden` e enviando o valor do atributo para tal `input` antes de submeter, para que o *backend* possa recebê-lo.